# Controlling MSG file draft/sent state

Tags: vba, ms-access, outlook

I've an Access database that records and saves email on the mailitem_send event.

Saved email looks like:
[image: this]

I want email to appear like an already sent email, like:
[image: this]

Anything I've tried doesn't change how the file is saved.

```
EmailAttachment.SaveAs Me.EmailFileLoc & Filename, OlSaveAsType.olMSG
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the time `MailItem.Send` or `Application.ItemSend` event fires, the mail is still unsent (you can cancel the submission). The earliest you can access the message in the sent state with the sender information populated is when it is moved to the Sent Items folder and the `Items.ItemAdd` event fires.

On a more general note, in your case `MailItem.Sent` property is false. OOM does not allow to change it at all. On the Extended MAPI level, the `MSGFLAG_UNSENT` bit can be removed from the `PR_MESSAGE_FLAGS` property only before the message is saved for the very first time (you can see the property in [OutlookSpy](http://www.dimastr.com/outspy)  - I am its author - if you click the IMessage button). This does not apply to messages saved as MSG files, and you can use [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (I am also its author) to change the flag (call `RDOSession.GetMessageFromMsgFile` / set `RDOMail.Sent` property to true / call `RDOMail.Save`)